# how to change div align in mobile version

Tags: html, css

I have 3 `div` in my html. `div1`, `div2`,`div3`. Now in mobile version I want to change the alignment of those `div`. I have given in below images.

[image: Desktop version]
[image: mobile version]

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  Div1
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-9" style="float:right;">
  Div3
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3" style="float:left;">
  Div2
 /div>
</div>
```

But didn't solved.

How to do that?

Anybody help please ?

Comment: Could you provide your css too?

Comment: Take a look at [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: @GäñèshKàlyâñKömmîsëttï...I have updated my with css...please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using bootstrap. If you re using Bootstrap 4 you can use the [ordering feature](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering) to easily achieve this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 order-md-1 order-sm-1">
    Div1
  </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 order-md-2 order-sm-3">
      Div2
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-9 order-md-3 order-sm-2">
      Div3
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/u1fbd0h2/2/)

**EDIT**

Since you are using bootstrap 3, reordering col-12 are not possible (e.g. col- * -push / col- * -pull). As alternative you can use [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items) or [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/CSS_Grid_Layout_and_Accessibility) to achieve this easily. See example below.

```
<div class="row reordered">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    Div1
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    Div2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    Div3
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS - Reordered using `grid`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) { //992 is the breakpoint of col-md
  .reordered {
   display: grid;
 }

 .col-md-3 {
   order: 2;
 }

.col-md-9 {
   order: 1;
 }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/snqupwaL/2/)

Comment: @Becky...Thats's awesome. But I am using `bootsrap 3`. I have apllied to this...but no change...Any other suggestion please?

Comment: I see. Then you can use a media query and use `flex-box` or `grid` to do that. I'll update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're using the Bootstrap framework in which case you can use the "[responsive utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#responsive-classes)" which are part of the framework's grid system to achieve what you require. To control the ordering of elements on the mobile version, you will also need to add some additional CSS.

The following changes to your HTML, along with the added CSS of `.order-row` etc, should achieve this for you:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .order-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .order-0 {
    order: 0;
  }
  .order-1 {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      Div1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row order-row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 order-1">
      Div2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 order-0">
      Div3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more information on how to use bootstraps responsive grid classes, [see this documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mix-and-match)

Comment: @ArafatRahman my apologies, just noticed that I missed that detail in your question. I've provided an update to this answer. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-12">
                Div1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-12">
                <div class="row flex-row-reverse flex-column-reverse">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
                        Div2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-12">
                        Div3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Div1
            
            
                
                    
                        Div2
                    
                    
                        Div3

Answer (score 0):

if you use bootstrap 4, you can use `order`

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  Div1
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-9 order-md-0 order-1">
  Div2
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3 order-md-1 order-0">
  Div3
 /div>
</div>
```

**Explanation**
the `Div2` will show on the left on viewport `md` and bigger, and it will shown under `Div3` if the viewport is smaller than `md`

Comment: I am not using bootstrap 4...I am using bootstrap 3