# how to change alignment of div in mobile version

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 div in my html. div1, div2,div3. Now in mobile version I want to change the alignment of those div. Please see the below images for better understand.

[image: desktop]
[image: mobile]

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  Div1
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-9" style="float:right;">
  Div3
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3" style="float:left;">
  Div2
 </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE: I am using bootstrap 3**

How to do that?

Anybody help please ?

Comment: duplicate of `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887520/how-to-change-div-align-in-mobile-version/55887568?noredirect=1#comment98434746_55887568`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Grid: column ordering](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering)

According to the mobile-first concept you need to define default view for mobile first in the right order.

- section 1
- section 3
- section 2

Then assign `col-md-push-3` for **section 3** and `col-md-pull-9` for **section 2** and define its width using `col-md-` class.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div>section 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-md-push-3">
      <div>section 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">
      <div>section 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered something similar to this question before. reordering col-12 are not possible with bootstrap-3 (push/pull). You can use grid together with a media query to do this.

```
<div class="row reordered">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    Div1
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    Div2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    Div3
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) { //col-md breakpoint
  .reordered {
   display: grid;
 }

 .reordered.col-md-3 {
   order: 2;
 }

.reordered.col-md-9 {
   order: 1;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
 .row {
   display: grid !important;
   grid-template-columns: auto !important;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Did you mean `grid`? You should avoid to use `!important`.

Comment: Yes i meant grid

Answer (score 0):

use   `col-sm-12` hopefully it will work